# working tampermonkey script not working on website

Tags: javascript

`<div id="captchaWindow" style="display: none;> </div>` I have working script to change display to block but it doesn't work on website I don't understand what I'm doing wrong and how they prevent my script from working.
(you press j to hide/show)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         captcha
// @namespace    c
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match       *://*.agar.io/*


// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("captchaWindow");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }

  }
  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(){
   if (event.which === 74)
   {myFunction();}
  });
```

My end goal is to "automate" hide captcha when it's valid and show again once it expire... I didn't find yet how it works (which element says it's valid).

Answer (score 0):

You need `myFunction();` at the end of your code.

Comment: didn't work, to clarify my initial code is perfectly working on  <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="fr">
<head>
 
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <title>captcha test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <!-- Corps de la page -->
 

 <button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>

 <div id="captchaWindow" style="display: none;">
  This is my captcha element.
  <div id="verifyUser"></div> 
</div> 



 </body>
</html>

Comment: I can even open inspect and set value to none and it will hide the div

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use another script and I just found out it's blocking mine, how do I close my question?

Comment: Fair enough. It worked for me on a random element only when myFunction(); was at the end. According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50321/can-i-close-my-question), you need 250 reputation to close your own question, which is annoying. You can make your own answer, but I think you can only accept it as best 2 days after you post the question.